# What's the best soundproofing solution to rubber coming off of double-paned transom windows?

Tags: windows, sound-proofing

Rubber between the two window panes are coming off of our double paned transom windows. Does the rubber have soundproofing capabilities? We live on a very busy street and are also looking for ways to soundproof. If so, what would be the best resolution?

Your feedback will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I'll take note of the cost questions. Yes, I believe it's the seal between the window panes. We were wondering what we could do to remedy this as it is an eyesore and we were hoping that repairing/replacing might dampen the noise.

Comment: The short answer is that sealed units like that aren't generally repairable--it's nearly impossible to get a good seal DIY, so you end up with moisture and dust inside. You'd order a new unit and install it into the frame using standard glazing techniques. I'd need more detail (better photos) to offer more advice.

Comment: @isherwood that's a short answer, but it's an answer. Might want to make one out of it.

Comment: I think DMoore covers it fairly well.

Answer (score 1):

The "rubber" falling out could be weatherstripping but is most likely the window gasket.

[image]

Example above is just one type, not your type.   But the gasket locks the window into the grooves around the wood.   The provides weather tightness with some very mild sound absorption abilities.

The fact that these windows look to be under an underhang means that the rain probably won't get through, bad gasket or not.   So for now it is aesthetics and slight insulation.

To replace these you might as well have a window or glass company come out and do the repair on site or to get brand new frames/windows.   Either way there will need to be some disassembling of the trim/window.

You could bypass that by gluing weatherstripping around the window frame and if you can get a slim band to look good - that could easily work for the short term.    More of a craft project.

Any sound issues you have, have almost zero to do with this.